# How to properly use information from NCBI gov

Tags: copyright, gov

I would like to ask you, if and how can I quote and copy (or read and reproduce) the research and all the data that is publically avaialble at the website of http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/

The questions is, because I am planning a launch of a new website based solely on research from this website. Because it's trustworthy. Ofcourse if I quote part of the research I will give a link at the bottom of my post. Is there anything else that I need to know?

I have read through the terms of use and I have found this

> Information that is created by or for the US government on this site is within the public domain. Public domain information on the National Library of Medicine (NLM) Web pages may be freely distributed and copied. However, it is requested that in any subsequent use of this work, NLM be given appropriate acknowledgment.

So I think I can use the data, but still would like to get your opinion too. The thing is I would like to create a website that is trustworthy and not just the marketing articles that we see elsewhere.

Comment: How is your website different from NCBI?

Answer (score 1):

You are one the right track. Quote, link, explain, add value, and you should be more than fine!!

Despite the fact that the information is in the public domain, search engines do not understand this well. For this reason, I suggest following the *fair use doctrine* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use) and not copy their work. If you do need to copy a whole work, make sure you use a canonical tag (https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en) to point to the original. I would suggest avoiding this as much as possible and sticking with fair use.